# Existence elimination in Lean 3

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic, automated-theorem-proving

Lean 3 is a theorem prover that implements the calculus of inductive constructions. Differently than Coq, Lean 3s kernel works proof irrelevant. This means that in the kernel of Lean all proofs of the same theorem are judgmentally (definitionally) equal and can be substituted for each other.

Does that mean that if I have `A : Type`, `P : A -> Prop`, and `p : (∃ x : A, P x)`, then there is no way to extract an actual `w : A` from `p` which satisfies `P w`?

I thought being able to extract witnesses from existence proofs is one of the main arguments for Martin-Löf style type theories.

Comment: You can do this in Lean with [classical.choice](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/axioms_and_computation.html#choice). Most Lean developments use choice freely.

Comment: No, if I use choice then I only know that I have some x such that P x, but I do not get a concrete term. For example, if I have the proposition $ P := \exists n : \mathbb N, prime \,n$, then I'd like to extract a concrete prime number from a proof of P.

Comment: That's not correct. You can use classical.some to get a concrete term and classical.some_spec to extract its property. Both derive from classical.choice.

Comment: I didn t mean to say that you re are not correct. I wanted to say that choice is not what I was looking for. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: For future reference, questions about proof assistants are borderline on topic here, and entirely on topic on [proofassistants.se].

Comment: To keep the record straight, Lean does *not* use a Martin-Lof style type theory. It is a variant of CIC. MLTT usually doesn't contain such an impredicative `Prop` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, in general there is no way how to extract an actual witness `w` for `p w` out of a proof `∃ x : A, p x`.
And the correct reference was given by Ali in the comments.
[In the documentation](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/axioms_and_computation.html#choice) the result

```
noncomputable theorem indefinite_description
{α : Sort*} (p : α → Prop) : (∃ x, p x) → {x // p x}
```

uses the choice axiom

```
axiom choice {α : Sort*} : nonempty α → α
```

in its derivation, and it is also mentioned that `propext`, `funext`, and `choice` taken together imply the law of excluded middle.
But this is, as mentioned at the start, *in general*.
There are types `A` for which we can extract witnesses (i.e. we can prove an instance of `indefinite_description`), and the most prominent example is for decidable predicates on `nat`.
But more generally, it holds for encodable types and decidable predicates. This can be found in the Lean standard library under the name [`encodable.choose_x`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/equiv/encodable/basic.html#encodable.choose_x)

Comment: It might be worth commenting, though, that at least in the case of Coq, the implementation essentially consists of going through natural numbers until it finds one that works (i.e. it pretty much starts over from scratch instead of extracting the witness from the existence proof).  And the role of the existence hypothesis is simply to use that in the proof that the search procedure will terminate.

Comment: @DanielSchepler this only works if the proposition is decidable.